# My hosts file under Mac OS X 10.8 is empty

Tags: hosts

I just opend my hosts file via the terminal and I must have accidentally wiped it last time I opened it!
Does anybody have the standard file content?

Comment: This may be off topic, however this was the solution to a problem that looked like a programming problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576566/2297345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine looks like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```