# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in nodejs for get call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express, restify

I am running a web server on node the code for which is given below

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer();

var quotes = [
  { author : 'Audrey Hepburn', text : "Nothing is impossible, the word itself says 'I'm possible'!"},
  { author : 'Walt Disney', text : "You may not realize it when it happens, but a kick in the teeth may be the best thing in the world for you"},
  { author : 'Unknown', text : "Even the greatest was once a beginner. Don't be afraid to take that first step."},
  { author : 'Neale Donald Walsch', text : "You are afraid to die, and you're afraid to live. What a way to exist."}
];

server.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json(quotes);
});

server.get('/quote/random', function(req, res) {
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  var q = quotes[id];
  res.json(q);
});

server.get('/quote/:id', function(req, res) {
  if(quotes.length <= req.params.id || req.params.id < 0) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    return res.send('Error 404: No quote found');
  }

  var q = quotes[req.params.id];
  res.json(q);
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3011);
```

And then i want to do a get request in the following code

```
var https = require('http');

/**
 * HOW TO Make an HTTP Call - GET
 */
// options for GET
var optionsget = {
    host : 'http://localhost',
    port : 3010,
    path : '/quote/random', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};

console.info('Options prepared:');
console.info(optionsget);
console.info('Do the GET call');

// do the GET request
var reqGet = https.request(optionsget, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    // uncomment it for header details
//  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);


    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('GET result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\nCall completed');
    });

});

reqGet.end();
reqGet.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I am just starting with node and i dont even know if this is the right way.
I want to test the performance of express and restify.I have done a apache benchmark test for the server code i wrote and found contradicting results that restify is better.So i want to test out some more by making calls to remote services and then later read write to mongodb.The above code is my starting point.I am getting the error

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

Am i atleast heading in the write direction? What is the right way to the kind of tests that i want to? Why did i get the result restify faster than express? Can anyone guide me to the best starting point tutorials for application in node/express/backbone and mongodb?

Comment: `process.stdout.alwrite.now(d)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690803/node-js-getaddrinfo-enotfound)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND means client was not able to connect to given address.
Please try specifying host without http:

```
var optionsget = {
    host : 'localhost',
    port : 3010,
    path : '/quote/random', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
    method : 'GET' // do GET
};
```

Regarding learning resources, you won't go wrong if you start with http://www.nodebeginner.org/ and then go through some good book to get more in-depth knowledge - I recommend [Professional Node.js](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118185463) , but there's many out there.

Comment: `getaddrinfo ENOUTFOUND means client was not able to connect...` -> Make sure that you get a reply when you ping that address using a terminal or prompt.

Comment: If you have `localhost` as your host and it still doesn't work, check your `\etc\hosts` file if it has this row: `127.0.0.1  localhost`.

Comment: If it doesn't work even if `hosts` files has the correct entry check `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has a line like

`hosts: mymachines files dns [!UNAVAIL=return] myhostname resolve
networks: files`.

`files` should occur before `[!UNAVAIL=return]`. 

That is what worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

Check host file which like this

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me! After hours of search, I found that the `/etc/hosts` file on my mac was empty!

After you change the file on the mac, run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` for the changed to take effect!

Answer (score 18):

for me it was because in /etc/hosts file the hostname is not added

Comment: What hostname did you add?

Comment: @PerStröm 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 9):

I can't explain why, but changing url parameter from having `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` on `mongodb.MongoClient.connect()` method on Windows 10 solved the issue.

Comment: Something similar worked on OSX sierra, I tried connecting with
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/meanhotel', function(err, db){......} 
But this worked instead:
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meanhotel', function(err, db){......}

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me too but I was setting up the S3 Adapter for PayloadCMS and MinIO locally (with docker run), for development.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that my endpoint was `http://tenant1.localhost`. While this somehow works in the browser, it did not with node.

I had to add the following line to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 tenant1.localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem and I fixed it by using right proxy.
Please double check your proxy settings if you are using proxy network.

Hope this will help you -

Answer (score 1):

> i have same issue with Amazon server i change my code to this

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    localAddress     : '35.160.300.66',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'rootdb',
});
```

check mysql node module
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');

  var options = {     
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 80,
      path: '/broadcast'
    };

  var requestLoop = setInterval(function(){

      http.get (options, function (resp) {
        resp.on('data', function (d) {
          console.log ('data!', d.toString());
        });
        resp.on('end', function (d) {
           console.log ('Finished !');
        });
      }).on('error', function (e) {
          console.log ('error:', e);
      });
  }, 10000);

var dns = require('dns'), cache = {};
dns._lookup = dns.lookup;
dns.lookup = function(domain, family, done) {
    if (!done) {
        done = family;
        family = null;
    }

    var key = domain+family;
    if (key in cache) {
        var ip = cache[key],
            ipv = ip.indexOf('.') !== -1 ? 4 : 6;

        return process.nextTick(function() {
            done(null, ip, ipv);
        });
    }

    dns._lookup(domain, family, function(err, ip, ipv) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        cache[key] = ip;
        done(null, ip, ipv);
    });
};

// Works fine (100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install a new ionic app, I got the same error as follows,
I tried many sources and found the mistake made in User Environment and System Environment unnecessarily included the PROXY value. 
I removed the ```user variables
http://host:port
PROXY

system Variables
http_proxy
http://username:password@host:port ````
and now it is working fine without trouble.

```
[ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?

        If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs

        Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host host:80
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out the issue was with my proxy password.

The error was:

> "Start npm npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND npm ERR!
> network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-1.14.1.tgz
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myUsername npm ERR! network This is
> a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most
> cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR!
> network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure
> that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm
> help config'

It turned out the interesting part was this one :

> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myUsername

My password, that was used in the proxy, had special characters like ! and #.
After I used percent encoding : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding I was able to run npm install. Before this I tried with a wrong password and a received a 407 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost:3000 error. Could not connect to my database. My issue was that I've created 2 different databases in one postgresql db server. All of my db server properties were set correctly. For example:
host: localhost
port: 5432
username: myUsername
password: xxxxxx

Only when I checked "Connection String" in my db server properties it had  different  dbname. Not the one I were expected it to pick up on. Just double check properties "connection string" as well in your database server properties.

Answer (score -3):

I was running into the same problem and after some trial and error discovered that my `hosts` file customisation was causing the problem.

My `localhost` DNS was overwritten and because of that a simple ping was failing:

```
$ ping http://localhost
# ping: cannot resolve http://localhost: Unknown host
```

Once I resolved the configuration of `/private/etc/hosts` file, pinging `localhost` successfully worked, and was no longer getting the error that you were seeing:

```
# Fatal error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Comment: You can't ping with http which is port 80. Ping uses ICMP with is port 1. You can ping localhost though.