# Failed to install browsers in playwriter while running the script in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, playwright-java

```
Downloading Chromium 113.0.5672.53 (playwright build v1060)[2m from https://playwright.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1060/chromium-win64.zip[22m
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND playwright.azureedge.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:95:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'playwright.azureedge.net'
}
Downloading Chromium 113.0.5672.53 (playwright build v1060)[2m from https://playwright-akamai.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1060/chromium-win64.zip[22m
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND playwright-akamai.azureedge.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:95:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'playwright-akamai.azureedge.net'
}
Downloading Chromium 113.0.5672.53 (playwright build v1060)[2m from https://playwright-verizon.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1060/chromium-win64.zip[22m
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND playwright-verizon.azureedge.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:95:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'playwright-verizon.azureedge.net'
}
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to download Chromium 113.0.5672.53 (playwright build v1060), caused by
Error: Download failure, code=1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright-java-2390916958096346510\package\lib\server\registry\browserFetcher.js:95:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create driver
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.createAndInstall(Driver.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.ensureDriverInstalled(Driver.java:57)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.createImpl(PlaywrightImpl.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.create(PlaywrightImpl.java:35)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:114)
    at PlayWright.Demo.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to install browsers, exit code: 1
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.jar.DriverJar.installBrowsers(DriverJar.java:100)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.jar.DriverJar.initialize(DriverJar.java:69)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.initialize(Driver.java:64)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.createAndInstall(Driver.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

[image]

Comment: please read this and edit your question
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` means client was not able to connect to given address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23259900/6505250). The error message looks like Java delegates to Node.js for downloading. Your IDE is pretty outdated. Maybe you use an outdated Node.js as well which might not be able to download via HTTP**S** with nowadays length of keys. Or maybe you are behind a proxy. Whatever, this does not seems to be related to Java or Eclipse.